# Photoshop makes images blurry when transforming

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I made a video to explain whats happening: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g3oSkKkvYb4

The image looks good until I press enter, then it gets really blurred. Is there any way to stop this?

Comment: If you want to transform your pixel art using the transform function then I would check out this question, see Rydrman's answer - [How can I prevent Photoshop from applying anti-aliasing to a layer when it's resized?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3004/how-can-i-prevent-photoshop-from-applying-anti-aliasing-to-a-layer-when-its-res)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you are enlarging the image more than its original size. That's why it looks blurry. If it is a vector image, double-click the smart object to open it in a new window and then transform it there.

Comment: But the thing is, it looks good until I press enter. If you watch the video, there are crisp edges and you can still tell what it is, until I confirm it. Is there a way to keep it as it is before I pressed enter?